# Saving Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I want to save and load a fitted Random Forest Classifier, but I get an error.

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, max_features = mf_val)
forest = forest.fit(L1[0:100], L2[0:100])
joblib.dump(forest, 'screening_forest/screening_forest.pkl')
forest2 = joblib.load('screening_forest/screening_forest.pkl')
```

The error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\mkolarek\Documents\other\TrackerResultAnalysis\ScreeningClassif
ier\ScreeningClassifier.py", line 67, in <module>
    forest2 = joblib.load('screening_forest/screening_forest.pkl')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py",
 line 425, in load
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py",
 line 285, in load_build
    Unpickler.load_build(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1217, in load_build
    setstate(state)
  File "_tree.pyx", line 2280, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__setstate__ (sklearn\
tree\_tree.c:18350)
ValueError: Did not recognise loaded array layout
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Do I have to initialize forest2 or something?

Comment: save a random forest! :)

Answer (score 8):

I solved it with cPickle instead:

```
with open('screening_forest/screening_forest.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(forest, f)

with open('screening_forest/screening_forest.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    forest2 = cPickle.load(f)
```

but a joblib solution could be useful as well.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work between machines in my case :( got the exact same error with pickle and cPickle

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method that you can try

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()

model.fit(data,lables)

import pickle

Model_file = 'model.pkl'

pickle.dump(model, open(Model_file, 'wb'))

'''Reloading the model
load the model from Saved file'''

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(Model_file, 'rb'))
```